# Exporting list of lists of numbers from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have received an output in GEE code editor in the form of a list of lists of numbers as shown below:

```
var list1 = ee.List([[1.7,2.4,3.1],[1.3,2.7,3.1],[1.4,2.4,3.2],[1.9,2.8,3.7]]);
```

I want to export this result in the form of a csv and for this, I tried the following:

```
Export.table.toDrive(ee.FeatureCollection(list1));
```

But it throws the error citing this:

```
Collection, argument 'features': Invalid type. Expected: List<Element>. Actual: List<List<Float>>.
```

Can you help as I am unable to understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `Export` to be able to reproduce the error, just use `print`:

```js
var list1 = ee.List([[1.7,2.4,3.1],[1.3,2.7,3.1],[1.4,2.4,3.2],[1.9,2.8,3.7]]);
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(list1)
print(fc)

Collection, argument 'features': Invalid type. Expected: List<Element>. Actual: List<List<Float>>
```

Depending in the output you want is what you have to do. I show you just a `csv` with one column with name `list` and one row (the `Feature`):

You have to create a `Feature` with a property in which you will "store" that list, and then create a `FeatureCollection` with that `Feature`

```js
var list1 = ee.List([[1.7,2.4,3.1],[1.3,2.7,3.1],[1.4,2.4,3.2],[1.9,2.8,3.7]]);
var features = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {'list': list1})])
print(features)
```

Comment: It worked but a further clarification required, please: the output csv when opened in excel environment gives the complete list in one cell. Is it possible to export such that it takes some kind of easily workable format?

Comment: that is why I said "*Depending in the output you want is what you have to do*". Take in count that every `Feature` is a row, so if you want many rows, you'll have to write many features